# Does not taking the update data

Tags: vb.net, webforms, reportviewer, rdlc

I have One `Dataset` binding in `Reportviewer`, My `dataset` Have two Paramters, in Report loud  data will displays in normally put the problem is when i pass the paremeters in new values `reportviewer` and I click  search `Button` the previous data in `reportviewer` does meat any changes.  means the newer searched data will not be displayed!

Here is my Code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
            mysession() 
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local 
            Dim rep As LocalReport = ReportViewer1.LocalReport 
            rep.ReportPath = "Leaving Report.rdlc" 
            Dim ds1 As DataSet = GetData() 

            Dim EMpReplt As New ReportDataSource() 
            EMpReplt.Name = "ProlDataSet_Lrepoert" 
            EMpReplt.Value = ds1.Tables("EMPData") 
            rep.DataSources.Add(EMpReplt) 
End sub 

 Private Function GetSalesData() 
        Dim ds As New DataSet 
        Dim sql As String = "select * from laeve where Status='" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & "' and Agent='" & Session("Agence") & "'" 
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql,con) 
            Dim mysqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command) 
            mysqlAdapter.Fill(ds, "EMPData") 
            mysqlAdapter.Dispose() 
            command.Dispose() 
        End Using 
        Return ds 
    End Function 
 End Sub 


Protected Sub Search_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh() 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the `.IsPostBack` [Using the WebForms ReportViewer Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
            mysession() 
   If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local 
            Dim rep As LocalReport = ReportViewer1.LocalReport 
            rep.ReportPath = "Leaving Report.rdlc" 
            Dim ds1 As DataSet = GetData() 

            Dim EMpReplt As New ReportDataSource() 
            EMpReplt.Name = "ProlDataSet_Lrepoert" 
            EMpReplt.Value = ds1.Tables("EMPData") 
            rep.DataSources.Add(EMpReplt) 
     End if
End sub
```

Comment: i all ready use i this way ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh() in page loud.

Comment: Reportviewer Does not meat any changes,

Comment: I got errer, Datasource has been not supplied instance name! if i change my code If page.ispostBack = False Then ----- End If /Its Ok Put No Data Has Displayed